# How do I get data from requested server page?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I got two php pages:
**client.php** and **server.php**

**server.php** is on my web server and what it does is open my amazon product page and get price data and serialize it and return it to **client.php**.

Now the problem I have is that **server.php** is getting the data, but when I return it and do `echo` after using `unserialize()`, it shows nothing. But if I do `echo` in **server.php**, it shows me all the data.

Why is this happening? Can anyone help me please?

This the code I have used:

**client.php**

```
$url = "http://www.myurl.com/iec/Server.php?asin=$asin&platform=$platform_variant";
$azn_data = file_get_contents($url);
$azn_data = unserialize($azn_data);
echo "\nReturned Data = $azn_data\n";
```

**server.php**

```
if(isset($_GET["asin"]))
     {
         $asin = $_GET["asin"];
         $platform = $_GET["platform"];
         echo "\nASIN = $asin\nPlatform = $platform";
         //Below line gets all serialize price data for my product
         $serialized_data = amazon_data_chooser($asin, $platform);

         return($serialized_data);
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Warning: No Data Found!";
     }
```

Comment: Funny joke, in `client.php` you try to get the content of a PHP file. Why you dont use `include`, `include_once`, `require` or `require_once` functions?

Comment: Because he wants the output of PHP code not the code itself.

Comment: `file_get_contents` will fire an HTTP request to the server and get the response of the server. The PHP script at that point was processed by the PHP interpreter and only the output will be fetched, not the source code.

Comment: @Bondye: Guessing by the file names, it would seem that they're hosted on different machines.  So including the code isn't really an option, but consuming it as a service is.

Comment: I have already tried it but it says: PHP Warning:  require_once(): URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

Comment: @David what you mean by consuming the code as service?

Comment: @Keyur: Is `Server.php` actually returning the data?  What does it give you if you go to the URL manually?  (Potentially inspect in something like FireBug to see more details.)

Comment: @Keyur: You don't consume the code as a service, you consume its output.  Which may indeed be your problem.  The output from `Server.php` is using `echo` for an error condition but `return` for the normal condition.  `return` may not do what you expect here.  Does it actually output any data?

Comment: @David it does show me when i go to that URL with GET variable passed in URL and also in terminal if i do print_r() before return;

Comment: @Keyur: So... if you output something with `print_r()` then you see output, but if you don't output anything then you don't see output?  I'm confused as to what you're actually trying to do here.  You have two separate and distinct applications.  One on the server, which needs to respond with usable HTTP output, and one on the client which needs to consume that output.  So what is the output?  `Server.php` needs to render _something_ in order for `Client.php` to see it.

Comment: @David Server.php returns an serialized array, but when i do print_r(unserialize($data)); it doesn't show anything but when i do print_r() before returning data in Server.php it does print the array. And what i want is to pass product ASIN and Country as a parameter in the URL and on other hand server.php will get those from $_GET and will get data from amazon for that product and send it back to client.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **server.php** , you need to replace your following line:

```
return($serialized_data);
```

for this one:

```
echo $serialized_data;
```

because client.php reads the **output** of server.php, `return` is used to pass information from functions to caller code.

**UPDATE**:
Apart from the fixes above, you're hitting a bug in `unserialize()` function that presents with some special combination of characters, which your data seems to have, the solution is to workaround the bug by `base64()` encoding the data prior to passing it to `serialize()` , like this:

In **client.php**:

```
$azn_data = unserialize(base64_decode($azn_data));
```

In **server.php**:

```
echo base64_encode($serialized_data);
```

Source for this fix [**here**](http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues) .

Comment: ok but how do i unserialize it in client.php because there is nothing in the return

Comment: Just the way you are already doing it, in client.php you do it right with $azn_data = unserialize($azn_data);

Comment: Do you mean amazon_data_chooser() returns nothing?

Comment: no it returns serialized data and i want to unserialize it in client.php

Comment: @Keyur: You need to output the string from `Server.php` in a way that `Client.php` can read it.  `echo` is probably the simplest way to do that.  `Client.php` isn't calling the _code_ in `Server.php`, it's calling it *as a web page*.  So `Server.php` needs to act like a web page and print the data.  Right now it's echoing the query string values.  But `return` is being used improperly here, it needs to echo the data as well.  (In fact, it should probably echo _only_ the data and not the query string values.)

Comment: @Keyur: Basically, when you go to the URL for `Server.php` manually in your browser and include the necessary query string parameters, you should see the serialized data in your browser (or at least in FireBug).  `Server.php` should have *no knowledge* of whether it's being accessed by `Client.php` or a web browser or any other standard `GET` request.

Comment: @David it is giving me output when i do echo in client.php but it is the page output of server.php so i can not process that data and what i want is an array or unserialized array.

Comment: @keyur In that case, can you paste the contents of $azn_data in client.php in http://www.pastebin.com and paste the link here so we can see why the output is wrong..

Comment: Ok I think I've found what the error is. going to write the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You are not serializing your data on server side so there is nothing to deserialize on client side.

```
return(serialize($serialized_data));
```

Edit:

```
if(isset($_GET["asin"]))
     {
         $asin = $_GET["asin"];
         $platform = $_GET["platform"];
         echo "\nASIN = $asin\nPlatform = $platform";
         //Below line gets all serialize price data for my product
         $serialized_data = amazon_data_chooser($asin, $platform);

         die(serialize($serialized_data));
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Warning: No Data Found!";
     }
```

Comment: sorry but the data is serialized in amazon_data_chooser() in Server.php

Comment: Give us a example of amazon_data_chooser() output. Check on client side is there any headers or other junk in content you receive.

Comment: Array
(
    [asin] => B007R3
    [product] => MACKs Earplugs
    [sellers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Care Girl
            [1] => Soul Healthcare
            [2] => Bodylife-uk
        )

    [prices] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.89
            [1] => 3.89
            [2] => 3.89
        )

    [postages] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.00
            [1] => 0.00
            [2] => 0.00
        )

    [product_rank] => 8359
    [department] => 
    [total_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.89
            [1] => 3.89
            [2] => 3.89
        ))

Comment: It's not serialized data, just array. Use serialize() function and echo the output instead of returning it.

Comment: a:8:{s:4:"asin";s:10:"B007R3RUVK";s:7:"product";s:47:"MACK'S® Slim Fit Soft Foam Earplugs (10 Pairs)";s:7:"sellers";a:3:{i:0;s:22:"Rubber Soul Healthcare";i:1;s:11:"Bodylife-uk";i:2;s:11:"Condom Girl";}s:6:"prices";a:3:{i:0;s:4:"3.89";i:1;s:4:"3.89";i:2;s:4:"3.89";}s:8:"postages";a:3:{i:0;s:4:"0.00";i:1;s:4:"0.00";i:2;s:4:"0.00";}s:12:"product_rank";s:4:"8359";s:10:"department";b:0;s:11:"total_price";a:3:{i:0;d:3.890000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875;i:1;d:3.890000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875;i:2;d:3.890000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875;}}

Comment: Now the data is serialized, print it on server side and unserialize on client side.

Comment: it's giving me this error: PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 712 bytes